# how to pass sql table name using session on other page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, session

I have pages name glass.aspx, shirt.aspx. these pages contain images. When any one click on image, they redirect to product.aspx page. Product.aspx contain all details of the image.

My code of product.aspx

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString=";Password="
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [id],[ImagePath],[ImageName],[details],[price] FROM [BestSherwani] WHERE ([id] = @id)">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" QueryStringField="id" Type="Decimal" />
        </SelectParameters>

        </asp:SqlDataSource> 


    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="300"
                 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath", "~/admin/{0}") %>' /><br />


         <asp:Label ID="ImageUrlLabel" Font-Size="XX-Large" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label><br />

            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" Font-Size="XX-Large" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text='<%# Eval("details") %>'></asp:Label><br />--%>
```

I want to pass session on below code when every any one click on any image

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [id],[ImagePath],[ImageName],[details],[price] FROM [ SESSION PASS ] WHERE ([id] = @id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to pass the table name to select from?

I believe the quickest way for you to make this work is to pass your table name in the query string and create your SelectCommand dynamically on the back end on your Product page.

**glass.aspx**

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href=product.aspx?producttype=bestsherwani>
             <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="300"
                  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath", "~/admin/{0}") %>' />
        </a><br />
```

**product.aspx code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // TODO, handle case of empty query string
      SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = @"SELECT [id],[ImagePath],[ImageName],[details],[price] FROM " + Request.QueryString["producttype"] + " WHERE ([id] = @id)";
}
```

This should do what you are you looking for, however your bigger issue is the way you have your data set up and it's potential for failure and unnecessary complexity.

It looks like you have a separate table for each of your products and this is not a good design.  Instead you should have one table and have a ProductType field [id with foreign key to separate type table].  You can then put the type in your Where clause on your product page.  As you have it now, an incorrectly passed table name will throw a big ugly SQL error.

You should also look into three tiered design and get your sql in stored procedures and use the ObjectDataSource.

Cheers

Comment: THAX FOR YOUR SOLUTION. CLIENT NEED EACH TABLE FOR EACH TABLE SO I HAVE TO DO IT LIKE THIS.

Comment: Great.  If i solved your problem, please accept the answer and/or upvote.  If I missed the mark, please let me know and I will see if I can help more.  If you really want to use a session variable [which i'm not a big fan of], you can use a link button on the glass page, set the session in a postback function and then redirect to the product page

Comment: It gives me error that incorrect syntax near where.

Comment: I copied your sql string from the SqlDataSource but looking at it, i'm curious about Where "id = @id".  it looks like you intend @id to be a passed parameter but where is it coming from?  are you not only selecting on the table name but also another id field?  if so, this will need to be grabbed from somewhere as having it currently in quotes will cause it to be passed as is and will indeed error.

Comment: When any person click on image, image id is passed and other details with that id , also fetched.

Comment: ah.  so you want to put that id in the query string along with the producttype in your anchor tag (?producttype=producttype=bestsherwani&imageid=<%# Eval("ImageId")) and then add it to your string on the products page just like you do for the table name

Comment: Yes sir.I want to do just like this.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR. I AM PASSING ProductDetails.aspx?producttype=BestPathaniSuit&id=10 AND IT IS WORKING LIKE BUTTER.

Comment: that is great news!  again, i would encourage you look into using ObjectDataSource connected to a BLL class and using 3-tiered design.  you will find it satisfying.  Please accept my answer if things are working :)

Comment: I am working in 3 tier but this client has very low budjet so i have to work in old approch. i am new in stackoverfollw so not able to mark your answer as solution.